# Merge two arrays of objects, skipping duplicate items

Tags: javascript

There are two array's response as follow:

```
Array1 = [{...},{...},{...} ...]; // array2 has exact same records as in array1
Array2 = [{BookingId: 1, Duration: 30, BookingDate: 12/09/2021 12:10},{BookingId: 2, Duration: 45, BookingDate: 12/09/2021 13:45}, ...];
```

now apply jquery merge on these arrays like:

```
var result = $.merge(Array1, Array2);
```

as a result both array have same data but showing duplicate results in a output.

Comment: [It is expected behavior](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+merge+arrays+duplicates+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciated you all for your efforts.

```
var oldIds = new Set(this.bookings.map(b => b.BookingId));
            var merged = [...response.filter(b => !oldIds.has(b.BookingId)), ...this.bookings];
            this.bookings = merged;
```

Its resolved!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to dedupe based on `BookingId` property, you may leverage [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const arr1 = [{BookingId: 1, Duration: 30, BookingDate: '12/09/2021 12:10'},{BookingId: 2, Duration: 45, BookingDate: '12/09/2021 13:45'}],
      arr2 = [{BookingId: 2, Duration: 45, BookingDate: '12/09/2021 13:45'}],
      
      
      merged = [
        ...[...arr1, ...arr2]
          .reduce((acc, record) => 
            (acc.set(record.BookingId, record), acc), new Map)
          .values()
      ]
      
console.log(merged)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

Comment: Why not Set?.....

Comment: @mplungjan: if you mean to keep track of (already) merged items checking up against the `Set` of `BookingId` it seems to me slower than simply overwriting duplicates. Besides, `Map` looks to me more suitable _semanttically_.